# Disable "HTML error checking for this file is disabled" hint in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

How do I get rid of the "HTML error checking for this file is disabled, you can enable it by this hint" hint in Netbeans? It appears as a warning on the first line of every .php file, so I have hundreds of these showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enable HTML error checking, click on the light bulb on the hint and you should be taken to the configuration screen to do that.

Comment: When I do this I get "End of file seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected "<!DOCTYPE html>" on every PHP file instead. I do not have HTML code in my PHP files, so enabling HTML validation on them doesn't make sense. I just want this "hint" to go away.

Comment: haha @Clive i accidentally close it in your way, but now how can i enable this features back?

Answer (score 4):

Go To Tools|Options|Editor, select "Hints" and language set to HTML. There you can choose what to use and what to not

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an option to turn off this error specifically. At least not just this error (each checkbox is a group of different errors).

Comment: I am also facing this problem years after you faced and it kills me.